# serializing a form jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to serialize my form data and send it via ajax
I have used serializeArray() which gives me
the approriate postdata.
The code is as follows :

```
var fields = $('#myform :input').serializeArray();
                jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field)
                {

                     values[field.name]  = field.value

                });
```

I want to pass `values[field.id] = field.value`
I want to use serializeArray() only becoz
it uses the standard W3C rules for successful controls 
to determine which elements it should include .

Comment: This question was asked earlier but removed??

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better approach is to use this jQuery Form Plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

I have used successfully in many projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a repost:

```
        var values = {};
        $("#myform :input").each(function(i, field) {
              values[field.id] = field.value;

        });

        JSON.stringify(values));
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s also [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link doesn’t answer the question; the text does. I merely added the link so that OP knows where to get more information if needed. “Use `jQuery#serialize`”, without any links, would be a valid answer as well.